# Calculating NDVI using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, function, arcgis-10.7

I have a custom function that I'm trying to write (using Arcpy in ArcGIS 10.7.1), but I'm having a little trouble writing a successful function because I'm new to custom function writing.

I want the function to check out the `spatial` extension, calculate the NDVI, reclassify the image based on specific parameters, set the extent to environment settings, and save the output. Here is the custom function that I tried to write:

```
#Defining function
def ndviCALC():
    if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

    #Create red and nir float objects and perform map algebra
    var1 = Float(nir)
    var2 = Float(red)
    num = Minus(var1, var2)
    denom = Plus(var1, var2)
    ndvi = Divide(num, denom)

    #Reclassify ndvi output
    outRc = Reclassify(ndvi, "VALUE", ndviRemap, "NODATA")

    #Apply environments when saving final output
    resultRc = ApplyEnvironment(outRc)

    #Save resulting output
    resultRc.save(output2)
```

The file is saved as "calcNdvi" as a ".py" file.

Also, I have previously used the `sys.path.append` procedure to update the path directory for importing python scripts.

Here is the script that I have written, trying to use the function:

```
# import required modules
import arcpy
import calcNdvi

#Import classes
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# set environments
env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\DemoFunctions\\tooldata"
env.overwriteOutput = True
env.extent = "Boundary.shp"
env.mask = "Boundary.shp"


# define inputs, outputs, and remap table
input = "LANDSAT8_20150609.tif"
nir = input + "\\Band_5"
red = input + "\\Band_4"
ndviRemap = arcpy.sa.RemapRange([[-1.0, 0.0, 1], [0.0, 0.2, 2], [0.2, 0.4, 3], [0.4, 0.6, 4], [0.6, 0.8, 5], [0.8, 1.0, 6]])
output1 = "LANDSAT8_20150609_NDVI.tif"
output2 = "LANDSAT8_20150609_NDVI_RC.tif"

#Use custom function
try:
    #Trying to call the custom function here
    ndviFunction = ndviCALC
    print "NDVI successfully saved to workspace directory"

except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print arcpy.GetMessages(2)

finally:
    arcpy.CheckInExtension("Spatial")
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    ndviFunction = ndviCALC
NameError: name 'ndviCALC' is not defined
```

**How can I write this function correctly so that my function works?**

Comment: It's because it's in a separate module.  Change the import to `from calcNdvi import ndviCALC`, or call it with `calcNdvi.ndviCALC()`

Comment: and don't forget to include the brackets `()` in a function call (as shown in @mikewatt's comment above).

Comment: @SonofaBeach @mikewatt I ran your code modifications, but now I'm getting a new error: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    ndviCALC()
  File "C:\calcNdvi.py", line 11, in ndviCALC
    import arcpy
NameError: global name 'arcpy' is not defined```. I imported arcpy in the first script, why would it be throwing that error?

Comment: I have updated this question in the following thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/344958/arcpy-custom-function-error-arcpy-is-not-defined